# nvd3.js ugly labels in pieChart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I draw a pie chart using nv.d3.js and this is result (I think it's a bit ugly):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9x96o9s0fhh1v36/2013-11-05_1822.png

Here is highcharts example:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hlc09kjkcolsjp/2013-11-05_1823.png

How can I fix that problem? Setting chart.staggerLabel(true) didn't help.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: What version of nvd3 are you using ?

Comment: NVD3 doesn't make any effort to produce nice labels -- if the highcharts example works for you, I suggest going with that.

Comment: The new version of nvd3 has a [labelThreshold](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/pie.js#L20). See if it works for you.

Comment: @shabeer90 1.1.14b. About labelThreshold - in my first picture "Google Chrome" has a big percentage, but label ('Google' word) climbs (is it right word?) on slice.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, then I would do something like http://redotheweb.com/DependencyWheel/

It isn't difficult to integrate into your current piechart if you are using the pure D3.js stuff, but I haven't ever used NVD3.js, so I don't know how well it integrates into that software.